# Python: extract string on webtext from a list of URL

Tags: python, regex, web, urllib2

I have a list of web text URL that I need to extract information from and then store these information in a list.
the string I need to extract always start with (P:  OR  C:   OR  F:) and always end by a ";".
I have trouble to make that work all together, any help would be greatly appreciated.

An example of webtext from one of the URL:

```
DR   Proteomes; UP000005640; Chromosome 3.
DR   Bgee; C9J872; -.
DR   ExpressionAtlas; C9J872; baseline and differential.
DR   GO; GO:0005634; C:nucleus; IBA:GO_Central.
DR   GO; GO:0005667; C:transcription factor complex; IEA:InterPro.
DR   GO; GO:0003677; F:DNA binding; IEA:UniProtKB-KW.
DR   GO; GO:0000981; F:sequence-specific DNA binding RNA polymerase II transcription factor activity; IBA:GO_Central.
DR   GO; GO:0003712; F:transcription cofactor activity; IEA:InterPro.
DR   GO; GO:0000278; P:mitotic cell cycle; IEA:InterPro.
```

Here the result expected  for searching after C:

```
['nucleus', 'transcription factor complex']
```

But it also need to go through  the different URL and append in the same list

An example of what I have tried so far without success:

```
import urllib2
import sys
import re
IDlist = ['C9JVZ1', 'C9JLN0', 'C9J872']

URLlist = ["http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"+x+".txt" for x in IDlist]
function_list = []
for item in URLlist:
    textfile = urllib2.urlopen(item)
    myfile = textfile.read()
    for line in myfile:
        function = re.search('P:(.+?);', line).group(1)
        function_list.append(function)
```

Comment: Are all your files formatted in exactly the same way?
From your example, it looks like you can simply read each line from the fourth line onwards, and from 24th (by eye) character until next ';' character.

Comment: No, the files are all different and the position of the desire string may change. the only thing that is not variable is that it start with C: and end with ";" however it may happen that in some of the text the desire string isn't there. So it might be a good thing to add an exception to the script in case of unfound string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated file that includes your dictionary.  Note that I changed the loop control to key on the file ID: that ID serves as the dictionary key.

```
import urllib2
import re

IDlist = ['C9JVZ1', 'C9JLN0', 'C9J872']
function_dict = {}

# Cycle through the data files, keyed by ID
for id in IDlist:

    # Start a new list of functions for this file.
    # Open the file and read line by line.
    function_list = []
    textfile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"+id+".txt")
    myfile = textfile.readlines()

    for line in myfile:

        # When you find a function tag, extract the function and add it to the list.
        found = re.search(' [PCF]:(.+?);', line)
        if found:
            function = found.group(1)
            function_list.append(function)

    # At end of file, insert the list into the dictionary.
    function_dict[id] = function_list

print function_dict
```

The output I get from your data is

```
{'C9JVZ1': [], 'C9J872': ['nucleus', 'transcription factor complex', 'DNA binding', 'sequence-specific DNA binding RNA polymerase II transcription factor activity', 'transcription cofactor activity', 'mitotic cell cycle', 'regulation of transcription from RNA polymerase II promoter', 'transcription, DNA-templated'], 'C9JLN0': ['cytosol']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it mostly work.
However there is apparently some entry in the text that a messing with the current regex. some of the string selected are " HGNC:1493;"
Is there a way to specify in the regex that there is a space (\s) in the front of the START C:   ?

Comment: Also I previously intended to store the matching strings in a list but it's probably not the best option to keep track of the correspondence of selected string and the original ID selected for the URL.
Is there a way to store the found strings in a dictionary instead of a list with each ID?
Something like {'C9JVZ1' : ['nucleus', 'transcription factor complex'], 'C9JLN0' : ['otherstring',' anotherone']}    ?

Comment: Edit of the first reply:  I had the Answer in my question  by adding \s in the START regex it solved the missmatch problem re.search('\s[C]:(.+?);', line)
I'm still wondering how to create a dictionary like in the second comment